# Fresh WP install succeeds then fails - path or permissions problem?

Tags: wordpress, installation

I've followed the install instructions on docs.civicrm.org site to make a fresh installation of CiviCRM in Wordpress on a local server (Synology NAS running Linux kernel).  All went fine, leading to message that CiviCRM was successfully installed but then screen refreshed to show this warning:

> Warning: include(/volume1/web/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US//%%E6/E65/E656EDCD%%wordpress.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /volume1/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1270 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/volume1/web/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US//%%E6/E65/E656EDCD%%wordpress.tpl.php' for inclusion (include_path=

The CiviCRM admin page is blank except for this warning.  I notice that there is a double // in the path to the compile directory. Could that be a bug?

The path exists down to [..]/templates_c/en_US/ but there are no folders below that.  I have checked that /en_US/ has permissions 755.

Answer (score 1):

The civicrm files directory `/volume1/web/wp-content/uploads/civicrm` don't have required permission. Either change the ownership of the directory or give 755 permission.

Comment: Thanks but no - this directory and all below it already has 755 and is owned by the same user as all other folders and files.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in that folder '/volume1/web/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US//%%E6/E65/', does that file (E656EDCD%%wordpress.tpl.php) exist?  Or, instead of that file, something like WRTXXX.TMP is there instead?

See my issue: New Install Civi 5.4.0 getting Uncaught Symfony Rename Error and Blank Screen